# How to draw an octagon with a star internally?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {8}
  \tikz\foreach \i in {1,...,\n}
    \fill (\i*360/\n:1) coordinate (n\i) circle(2 pt)
     \ifnum \i>0 foreach \j in {\i+1,\i+4}{(n\i) edge (n\j)} \fi;

\end{document}
```

which leads to:

[image]

I want to make an octagon with this type of edges, but I don't know why the edges bewteen \i and \i+1 are not showing up. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome! Since you are loading `shapes.geometric`, you could just do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt}]
 \draw node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=8,draw,minimum size=2cm]
 (p8){}
  foreach \X[count=\Y] in {5,...,8} {(p8.corner \X) node[dot](n-\X){}
    -- (p8.corner \Y) node[dot](n-\Y){} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, there are IMHO better tools available: the `graphs` library. While it is true that there are not as many examples for those on this site available as for the above (which appeared several times in slight variations), I think this one will be much more powerful if you are really into graph drawing.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[nodes={circle,fill,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt}]
 \graph[empty nodes] { 
  {subgraph C_n [n=8,radius=1cm, counterclockwise] -- 
    0[coordinate]}; 
    };
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]